# How to merge 2 transparent png's in python Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have 2 transparent PNG images of the same size (142,43). I am trying to vertically stack them. This is one of them:

[image: yes]

The end result should be like this (142,86):

[image: yes]

It also should retain its transparancy.

I've tried the following code:

```
from PIL import Image

img_list = [Image.open("example.png"), Image.open("example.png")]
bg = Image.open("1x1_transparent.png")

bg = bg.resize(size=(142, 43*2))
img_list[0] = img_list[0].convert('RGBA')

bg.paste(img_list[0], (0, 0), img_list[0])

bg.save('final.png')
```

Which imports a 1x1 transparent image, resizes it to the final target size, then tries to put the first image on it. This does not work. The saved image 'final.png' shows an empty image.

Any thoughts what I would be doing wrong?

Comment: Wild guess: because `resize` does not mutate the object, try `bg = bg.resize(size=(142, 43*2))` instead.

Comment: Ah, indeed. You are correct, it does not. Too bad it still shows an empty image after changing that line.

Comment: @Kevin Scratch that, it does work now. Thanks! Post what you said as an answer and I will accept it. Such a stupid little thing ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your output doesn't seem properly sized, it's probably because of this line:

```
bg.resize(size=(142, 43*2))
```

`resize` returns a new version of the image, leaving the original one unmodified. Try assigning the returned value to something so you can do additional operations on it and ultimately save the output.

```
bg = bg.resize(size=(142, 43*2))
```